# App Store .app bundle issue - how do I solve it?

Tags: xcode, certificate, store

I created my app and it's ready to go, but when I try to upload it to the App Store, it says there are some certificates missing. Now that I remember, I don't think I got Distribution Certificates beforehand...my own fault, I know. But what I'm asking is that does this mean that the app I've already built can't be used or can I transfer newly acquired certificate information to my current app in Xcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just load up the new certificate and recompile then reupload.  It's no biggy.  Just follow Apple's guide.

Comment: Where would you find Apple's Guide for loading up certificates into an Xcode project?